# Stop Image Border in a nested DIV

Tags: html, css

I am making a Tumblr theme and I'm having to get creative to make my pages look the way I want them too.

One issue I'm running into is that I want a green border and a max width of 150 on any images on individual pages, but the template for individual pages is used for text posts on the index page, so my index page images are being set to have borders and a max width of 150px, which is not right.

Luckily there is a code on tumblr that lets me execute certain code of someone is looking at the index page. So is there any way I can make a second div that negates the border and size rules in the first div? Here is my code:

```
.text img{ //for individual pages
    max-width:150px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 5px 3px 0;
    border: 3px solid #52B472;
}

.notpage img{ //for index page
    max-width: 500px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="notpage">
        In a perfect world, there would be no borders or max width on images in this div.
    </div>
</div>
```

Sadly, the CSS from the 'text' div carries into the 'notpage' div. So does anyone know of any way I can negate the first div's CSS in the nested div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
.notpage img{ //for index page
```

to

```
.text .notpage img{ //for index page
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
max-width: 500px !important;
border: none !important;
```

It's not very good practice, though.